# Stripe IOS SDK not matching AllResponseFields?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I'm trying to do a simple count check for a customer to see if they need to add a source before moving onto another page. However, my calls to the STPCustomer object's attributes are not matching the information for the full response.

I've tried clearing the customer cache and reloading the customer, but uh... still no match.

Here's a truncated like, essentials code.  The class has the STPPaymentContextDelegate attached.

```
private var customerContext = STPCustomerContext? 
private var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext? 

func setupStripe() {
self.paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: self.customerContext!)

    self.paymentContext?.hostViewController = self
    self.paymentContext?.delegate = self

    self.paymentView = STPPaymentMethodsViewController(configuration: STPPaymentConfiguration.shared(), theme: STPTheme.default(), customerContext: self.customerContext!, delegate: self)
}

func getCustomerSources() {

if let customer = customerContext.retrieveCustomer({ (customer, error) in
        if customer != nil {
             print(customer.sources.count)
             print(customer.sources)
             print(customer.allResponseFields)
        }
    })
}
```

When I run `getCustomerSources()` on the test customer, I am expecting:

```
 1
 [ba_1Dvf46LrBVaGM6Sq9qIYhOlJ]
 AnyHashable("id"): cus_number, AnyHashable("email"): rosa_diaz@gmail.com, AnyHashable("default_source"): ba_1Dvf46LrBVaGM6Sq9qIYhOlJ, AnyHashable("created"): 1548220659, AnyHashable("description"): LiG8WbVhT8SVhta8LdfUuWzOwQn2, AnyHashable("livemode"): 0, AnyHashable("object"): customer, AnyHashable("sources"): {
  data =     (
            {
        "bank_name" = "STRIPE TEST BANK";
        country = US;
        currency = usd;
        customer = "cus_EOQzwwGPjzopjS";
        fingerprint = 1AQMB9nzeGSGXHst;
        id = "ba_1Dvf46LrBVaGM6Sq9qIYhOlJ";
        last4 = 6789;
        metadata =             {
        };
        object = "bank_account";
        "routing_number" = 110000000;
        status = verified;
    }
   );
   "has_more" = 0;
   object = list;
   "total_count" = 1;
   url = "/v1/customers/cus_EOQzwwGPjzopjS/sources";
}])
```

However, instead of my `1` and `ba_1Dvf46LrBVaGM6Sq9qIYhOlJ`, I am getting `0` and `[]`. **But** the **allResponseFields** section is the same.

Any ideas as to why there's a discrepancy between what the STPCustomer object attributes are returning and what the actual response is telling me?

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say what's going on without knowing more about the `error` parameter that your callback receives. It sounds like there might be an error parsing the API response, and printing the `error` passed into your `retrieveCustomer` block should give you a better idea about what's going on. If the error persists I'd recommend contacting support@stripe.com with details, as they can help directly with iOS app questions!

Comment: Added the error parameter just to see if there was a response - and there is no response. :') Thanks for the tips, however - I'll email Stripe and see if we can get this figured out.

Comment: Well, I'll let Stripe support help you but I just noticed that you never initialize the `customerContext` variable. Since it's an optional, calling customerContext.retrieveType() is a no-op. What you want to do is [initialize the STPCustomerContext with your key provider implementation](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPCustomerContext.html#/c:objc(cs)STPCustomerContext(im)initWithKeyProvider:).

Comment: I’ve reread the API and it turns out that STPBankAccounts don’t conform to the STPPaymentMethod protocol or... something. Either way, nothing besides STPCards are returned j the STPCustomerContext call because the SDK ignores all the other responses.